# How can I execute PySpark Stream with Azure Storage directory as a streaming data source

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, spark-streaming

I wanted to execute Spark Structured Stream Job with Azure Blob Storage as a Source for my stream.

Something like below:

```
spark_df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("blob") \
  .options(**blobConf) \
  .load()
```

How can I do it using PySpark ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work: what you've tried, where you're stuck, errors, output issues, etc. Currently this is too broad, without any specifics.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can run spark jobs on Azure batch with Azure container and blob service. Azure batch is used to run the jobs because they are low in cost.

To do this we need few required setup like Storage account, container registry and Azure batch to run jobs.

Below is the sample python code to run a simple spark job:

```
import argparse  
  
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  
  
import config  
  
  
def get_azure_spark_connection(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):  
    spark = (  
        SparkSession.builder  
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.3')  
            .config('spark.hadoop.fs.azure', "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")  
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key." + storage_account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net",  
                    storage_account_key)  
            .appName("AzureSparkDemo")  
            .getOrCreate())  
  
    (spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.wasbs.impl",  
                                                       "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem"))  
    return spark  
  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="input file to parse", type=str)  
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="result file to write", type=str)  
    args = parser.parse_args()  
    spark = get_azure_spark_connection(config.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, config.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)  
    df = (spark.read.option("header", "true")  
          .option("delimiter", ",")  
          .option("inferSchema", "true")  
          .csv(args.input))  
    df.registerTempTable("airlines")  
    result = spark.sql("""  
      select Year, Month, DayofMonth, _avg_(ArrDelay) as avg_ArrDelay, _avg_(DepDelay) as avg_DepDelay  
      from airlines   
      group by Year, Month, DayofMonth  
""")  
    result.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(args.output)
```

Below are the requirements which are used:

```
azure  
azure-storage  
azure-storage-blob  
pyspark==2.4.0
```

You can refer to these [blogs](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/run-spark-jobs-on-azure-batch-using-azure-container-registry-and-blob-storage-10a60bd78f90) to understand more about running Jobs with Azure storage using python.